# Set notation - problem

Tags: notation

I have problem with a notation used in an information theory course.

> Let $N = \lbrace 1,\dots, n \rbrace$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

What does $2^{N}$ mean/denote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It denotes all the binary sequences of length $n$. This set can also be identified with the power set of $N$.

Comment: It can be proved that $\mathbb R\cong ~^{\mathbb N}\{0,1\}$. So $2^{ N}$ is $\mathbb R$ as well.

Comment: @Babak: Note that in here $N$ is finite, not $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it means the power set of $N$.

Answer (score 1):

The set of subsets of N             .